# Browser not updating after remove or add a class in HTML element using Tailwind-CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, tailwind-css

I have a span element with `extendSearch` id that when clicked should expand or collapse the form element with the `searchSection` id. The collapse and expand is based on adding or removing the css `hidden` class.

CSS code in addition to Tailwind-css:

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML code

```html
<span id="extendSearch" class="cursor-pointer px-2 font-xl mr-2">-</span>
<form id="searchSection" method="post" class="p-5 w-full md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-4">
    <label>Search</label>
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Javascript code

```js
let extendSearch = document.getElementById("extendSearch");
let searchSection = document.getElementById("searchSection");

extendSearch.addEventListener('click', () => {

   if (searchSection.classList.contains('hidden')) {
       searchSection.classList.remove('hidden');
       extendSearch.innerText = "-";
    } else {
        searchSection.classList.add('hidden');
        extendSearch.innerText = "+";
    }

});
```

For some reason this code works pretty well wen i have *developer tools* open. i.e, The `classList` gets updated, the text of the span element gets updated and the browser renders the changes (the form disappears and appears).

But when the developer tools are closed the `classList` gets updated, the text of the span element as well but the browser doesn't render the changes. The behavior is the same on Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

I tried to use `.toogle()` but the behavior is the same. I tried to remove the `eventListener` and call a method `onclik` in the `span` tag, but it also has the same behavior.

Comment: Would need to see an [mcve] of this issue.  The developer tools being open/close should not affect this logic at all.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`?

Comment: Not a clean solution but if nothing works, please try triggering a window resize event.

Comment: seems to be working correctly with your code in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/r7xjndoz/3/).  You want to switch between + and - when clicked?

Comment: @AlexH that option is not valid for my case, it would leave a withe space when i don't intend to have one. It would break my design.

Comment: @ChrisL as i described in my question, the code works well in certain cases. I recommend you to read the last section of my comment, i describe my goal and the current behavior.

Comment: What comment?  I read your entire question.  I used your code in jsfiddle without developer tools open and it works fine.   Have you uploaded your code to a webserver to view in chrome and edge?  What is the link to that so I can see the issue.

Comment: I created an actual webpage with your code and uploaded it to one of [my domains](https://www.golden-painting.com/test.html) and it seems to work fine with or without DevTools open when using Chrome.  Works in Edge also.  Sounds like your issue is local.

Comment: Hi @ChrisL, i love your enthusiasm in trying to solve this problem. Can you check this https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/discussions/1918. I'm a bit busy now, that's why i didn't write an answer.

Comment: You should have mentioned in your question and tagged that you are using tailwind-css.  If you would have provided the code necessary to reproduce the issue as the very first comment said (the tailwind css for your other classes), the issue would have been solved very quickly.   Your code is working as expected but your class is being overridden.  I see that you solved it over at the tailwind support site.

Comment: So to wrap it up, yo have vertical dev-tools, right? The dynamic `.hidden` class was overridden by (static) `.md:grid`, that is effective only for "wider" screens, so it produced that "does not work without dev-tools open"? Amusing :]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the closing tag on your `<form>` tag. I used your code and simply added a closing `</form>` tag and added some content inside the form and it worked for me.

```
<span id="extendSearch" class="cursor-pointer px-2 font-xl mr-2">-</span>
<form id="searchSection" method="post" class="p-5 w-full md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-4">
  <input type="text"> <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Try changing your HTML to this and see if it works.

Comment: Inside my code i have a closing tag for the `<form/>` tag.

Comment: This is just a guess at an answer and not actually a solution.  The code works with or without the closing tag.  That is not the issue.  You should test your solution before posting and you would see that a quick mention of the closing tag should be in a comment.  It would be helpful to stackoverflow if you deleted this answer since questions that have wrong answers often get overlooked and may never get the correct answer.

Comment: @ChrisL this was not a guess, the original post did not have a closing tag or any html inside the form. So there was nothing to display or hide. I did in fact test my solution, why would you presume that I did not test it?